Closure of a question for "lack of focus" when it is entirely focused and clear
This question Is the experience of love evidence that we are more than bodies and brain chemistry? was closed for "lack of focus".  The question itself is perfectly clear.  It is a citation of the most blatantly irreducible qualia and ideas (Love, which is both an experience and an abstraction) to challenge materialist/physicalist reductionism.  There is nothing unclear whatsoever in what the question was about, and IF one had an answer, how to answer it.
The question itself has been central to philosophy of mind, and physicalism, for most oof a century.  And has recently been highlighted as having significant sociological effect on our general population and politics in Charles Taylor's "A Secular Age"
What we got in the comments were a series of poorly justified statements:

"Please edit to identify the reasoning that leads to the conclusion that love is more than the result of physical processes." and  ' "X cannot be reduced to" is not an argument'.  And "emotions & experiences might be hard to measure, but they can be, we known a lot about the amygdala & oxytocin now".

The failure of physicalist reductionism to account for qualia is called the hard problem of consciousness, and there is consensus it has not been solved.  The same is true for the similarly hard but less well known problem of abstractions.  No competent commentator here who is qualified to make close votes should not know that.

"asserting that arguments feel logical in a fuzzy way does not, by itself, necessarily make them logical"

Logic and reasoning do not themselves close logically (see the Munchausen Trilemma). A "fuzzy" approximation to "logic" is the best we can ever achieve.  Starting with an observation that is central to life, and accepted as irreducible to physics, and concluding that one must therefore operate off an irreducible metaphysics is actually perfectly valid logic, within the limits of what one can expect anyone to post with less than a tome.

"It's rhetoric, that uses a series of fallacies." 'Most people are familiar with the term "lying for Jesus".'

No fallacies or lies are identified, just implied thru innuendo.

"Emergent complexity from simple foundations is the universe you live in, my friend."  and "Modern science takes complex behaviors to be emergent from physics."

Both of these claims are far more confident than science actually is about emergence.  We have no emergence theory.  And we have leading physicists claim that physics is so well understood there is no space for dualist emergence or dualist interactionism (Sean Carroll, The Big Picture). Also, as emergence seems to operate at levels above physics, the "from physics" is not actually what modern science thinks either.
Note that postulating emergence is to ACCEPT the supposedly "lying" and "fallacious" or non-existent argument, as emergence is a possible way around it.  But however, postulate strong emergence and one then has pluralism.
The highest rated answer is also just another undocumented assertion that physicalism has solved the hard problem of consciousness, in the opinion of the writer:   https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/118997/29339
I have seen a pattern over the last several months of some posters trying to close every philosophy of religion question.  Is the effort to censor topics on this board now extending to other rivals to physicalism?  Or is there actually a legitimate reason to close this question?

I can see that the question lacks focus. It quotes a rambling argument that makes many different points. It talks about love but then also about free will. The questioner then asked, "What is an overview of all the problems with this type of informal reasoning?" That's really unfocused - not even all the problems in the arguments presented, but all the problems in those types of arguments. The question would be ok if the free will and love parts were split into two questions, and if the central question of each was made more specific.

Free will is a similarly obvious aspect of our world, that is similarly denied for ideological reasons by a large faction within philosophy. Adding that in is to reinforce Charles Taylor's point, that it isn't just love, it is a whole slew of central aspects of our life that are incompatible with rationalist materialism: selfhood, agency, values, and morality. Taylor calls this "enchantment", and this collection of value and meaning is what is lost when one adopts reductive secularism.  The OP would have been better served by having read Taylor first, but CITING Taylor should be in the answer.

@causative  forgot to "at"

If an argument rests on a whole slew of different aspects of our life, then still, that's not focused. A question should focus on one aspect at a time. "Does aspect-of-life A support thesis X?" and "Does aspect-of-life B support thesis X?" should be separate questions. (Also, though it's not relevant to whether the question is focused, the arguments quoted in the question make no sense at all. "Love can't be physically based because there are different categorizations of it"? What? Total non sequitur.)

@causative Consilience is the accumulation of distinct, discrete, yet related evidences and lines of inquiry to support a theory, conclusion, or reality.  It is a central feature of empiricism.   It is also a critical feature to look for in sociology in particular, as that science has a lot of noise in its data, and looking for consilience is a very important tool for sorting out false signals from real ones.  Dismissing consilience reasoning on these boards, and closing consilience references strikes me as counterproductive.
